# Loop to create lines chart in canvasjs

Tags: javascript, charts, canvasjs

I have an array Object:

```
  total = 
   [
    {
      date: 5/12/2017,
      count: 5,
      type: A
     },
     {
      date: 5/15/2017,
      count: 15,
      type: A
     },
     {
      date: 5/12/2017,
      count: 4,
      type: B
     },
     {
      date: 5/15/2017,
      count: 5,
      type: C
     }..
    ]
```

I wondering how to loop them in a line chart using [CanvasJS](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-types/html5-line-chart/), each line presents each type, the x-axis presents date, the y-axis presents count

Here is what I have so far:

```
     var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
        {
            title: {
                text: "My Counts"
            },
            axisX: {
                title: "Date",
            },
            axisY: {
                title: "Count"
            },
            data: []
           });
```

Comment: There are quite some mistakes in your code. String needs to be quoted eg(type: "A"). Also, you can't store date like that as it's not just a number. You need to either convert it to JS timeStamp or store it as a string. If you choose it to store as a string, you'll need to reformat it before JS accepts it as a valid date. Once these mistakes has been fixed, you can run a for loop to store dataPoints for chart as answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a for loop over your array and store dataPoints in different variable to later use it in your chart.

```
var dps1 = [];
var dps2 = [];
var dps3 = [];

for(var i = 0; i < total.length; i++) {
    if(total[i].type === "A") {
        dps1.push({x: new Date(total[i].date), y: total[i].count});
    } else if(total[i].type === "B") {
        dps2.push({x: new Date(total[i].date), y: total[i].count});
    } else if(total[i].type === "C") {
        dps3.push({x: new Date(total[i].date), y: total[i].count});
    }
}
```

Once you store you dataPoints, you'll need to use it in your chart.

```
data: [{
    type: "line",
    dataPoints: dps1
}, {
    type: "line",
    dataPoints: dps2
}, {
    type: "line",
    dataPoints: dps3
}]
```